# Numerical solution of nonlinear boundary value problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics, nonlinear, boundary-condition-at-infinity

I want to solve the following nonlinear boundary value problem. The results are very good in small domains, but when I increased the domain, the results become unstable, I tried a lot of internal features of Mathematica, but the problem still appears.

for example for

```
dstar = 10;
{WCLFP, WCLFN} = NDSolveValue[{0.75/(0.25 + E^(-1.5 w2p[r])) == 
    1 + 1.49 D[w2p[r], {r, 2}], 
    0.75/(0.25 + E^(-1.5 w2n[r])) == 1 + 1.49 D[w2n[r], {r, 2}], 
    w2p[0] - w2n[0] == -23.21, w2p'[0] + w2n'[0] == 0, 
    w2p'[dstar] == 0, w2n'[dstar] == 0}, {w2p, w2n}, {r, 0, 9.54}, 
   Method -> {"Shooting", "StartingInitialConditions" -> {w2p[0] == -(23.21/2), 
       w2n[0] == +(23.21/2)}}];
Plot[{Evaluate[WCLFP[r]], Evaluate[WCLFN[r]]}, {r, 0, dstar}, PlotRange -> All]
```

and the results are very good

[image]

however there is an error when I increased (dstar).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This system of second-order nonlinear ODEs, like many others in this site, is difficult to solve numerically, because the desired asymptotic solution is a separatrix.  As a consequence, infinitesimal numerical errors grow exponentially.  Several methods have been demonstrated on this site to extend the range of integration somewhat, mostly involving very good initial guesses and high `WorkingPrecision`.  Note that integrating a coupled set of second-order nonlinear ODEs typically is far harder than integrating a single second-order nonlinear ODE.

However, this particular pair of second-order nonlinear ODEs can be integrated in a fairly straightforward manner.  Begin by noting that each of the ODEs can be written as

```
eq1 = 149/100 w2''[r] == 3/(1 + 4 E^(-3/2 w2[r])) - 1
```

where `w2` represents either of the two dependent variables, `{w2p, w2n}`.  At large `r`, the desired solution has vanishingly small `w2''[r]`, which permits the asymptotic value of `w2` to be determined algebraically.

```
w20 = w2[r] /. Flatten@Solve[eq1[[2]] == 0, w2[r]] /. C[1] -> 0
(*  (2 Log[2])/3 *)
```

Next, `eq1` can be multiplied by `w2'[r]` and integrated once to yield

```
149/200 w2'[r]^2 + c == Integrate[eq1[[2]], w2[r]]
(* c + 149/200 w2'[r]^2 == 2 Log[4 + E^((3 w2[r])/2)] - w2[r] *)
```

where `c` is a constant of integration.  It, in turn, is determined by using the large `r` boundary condition that `w2'[r]` also is vanishingly small.

```
% /. {w2'[r] -> 0, w2[r] -> w20} /. Equal -> Rule
(* c -> -((2 Log[2])/3) + 2 Log[6] *)
```

which then leads to

```
eq2 = Flatten@Solve[%% /. %, w2'[r]] /. Rule -> Equal
(* {w2'[r] == -10 Sqrt[2/447] Sqrt[2 Log[2] - 6 Log[6] + 6 Log[4 + E^((3 w2[r])/2)] -
        3 w2[r]], 
    w2'[r] == 10 Sqrt[2/447] Sqrt[2 Log[2] - 6 Log[6] + 6 Log[4 + E^((3 w2[r])/2)] - 
        3 w2[r]]} *)
```

`w2` in the first equation of `eq2` can be identified as `w2n`, and in the second equation as `w2p`.

```
eq2[[2]] = eq2[[2]] /. {w2'[r] -> w2p'[r], w2[r] -> w2p[r]};
eq2[[1]] = eq2[[1]] /. {w2'[r] -> w2n'[r], w2[r] -> w2n[r]};
eq2
(* {w2n'[r] == -10 Sqrt[2/447] Sqrt[2 Log[2] - 6 Log[6] + 6 Log[4 + E^((3 w2n[r])/2)] - 
        3 w2n[r]], 
    w2p'[r] == 10 Sqrt[2/447] Sqrt[2 Log[2] - 6 Log[6] + 6 Log[4 + E^((3 w2p[r])/2)] - 
        3 w2p[r]]} *)
```

At this point, the pair of second-order ODEs has been simplified to a pair of first-order ODEs, and the integration converted from a boundary value problem to an initial value problem.  Using the `r == 0` boundary conditions from the question,

```
(w2p'[0] + w2n'[0] == 0, w2p[0] - w2n[0] == -2321/100}
```

then yields,

```
bc = FindRoot[{((eq2[[1, 2]] + eq2[[2, 2]]) /. r -> 0) == 0, 
    w2p[0] - w2n[0] == -2321/100}, {{w2p[0], -12}, { w2n[0], 12}}] /. Rule -> Equal
(* {w2p[0] == -14.5491, w2n[0] == 8.66086} *)
```

`eq2` with `bc` can be integrated numerically without difficulty.

```
dstar = 40;
sp = Flatten@NDSolveValue[{eq2[[2]], bc[[1]]}, w2p[r], {r, 0, dstar}];
sn = Flatten@NDSolveValue[{eq2[[1]], bc[[2]]}, w2n[r], {r, 0, dstar}];
Plot[{sp, sn}, {r, 0, dstar}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

As expected, `wp2[dstar]` and `w2n[dstar]` agree well with the asymptotic result, `w20`.

```
Chop[{sp, sn, w20 // N} /. r -> dstar]
(* {0.462098, 0.462098, 0.462098} *)
```

Comment: @ bbgodfrey I think, this method is correct just for the cases r is very large number, and for other cases when r is not large number, is incorrect? I cheched with small numbers, results are not same with mathematica solver

Comment: @hesamaero My analysis assumes that `dstar` is large but make no other approximation.